# Ho, Hum! What Am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Ho, hum!
> I'm grand and tall!
> Sharp and dull, I am not small!
> Kick my legs, but I won't fall!
> Larger than a market stall!
> Some see me balance atop ball!
> But I prefer the grass and all!
> Asia, Africa Central!

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> an **ELEPHANT**

*I'm grand and tall!*
*Sharp and dull, I am not small!*

> Elephants are among the largest land animals on the planet (*grand and tall... not small*), with *sharp* tusks and *dull* grey skin.

*Kick my legs, but I won't fall!*
*Larger than a market stall!*

> Elephants are sturdy beasts, unlikely to be toppled by a kick or a push, partly because of their size and bulk (*larger than a market stall*).

*Some see me balance atop ball!*
*But I prefer the grass and all!*
*Asia, Africa Central!*

> Elephants are native to the grasslands of Asia and Africa. When taken into captivity they have historically been popular attractions at circuses (see Disney's *Dumbo* for starters...), where an audience might see one performing tricks like balancing on a ball. But they're far more majestic when you can see them roaming free in the wild, doing what they do naturally!